# Providers or stateful widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on my first real flutter project, and I need to create a simple dice. 
To keep my code clear, I created a dice.dart file in which I coded a class Dice, containing a number, a void method rollDice and a getter returning the number.

I now want to create a stateful DiceWidget (would return a RaisedButton that shows the number of the dice) that I can instantiate on different pages, and from which I could get the number out of it... Do I have to create a provider on my class Dice to do so ? Or is there an other nicer way I don't know about, for example with just stateful widgets ?

Thank you for your answers !
Axel.

Comment: If you want to keep the state of your `Dice` between pages of your app, so yes, you need a `Provider<Dice>`

Answer (score 0):

Your going on right track as every page that's gives a number of dice by creating each page a stateful widgets

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you, I came up with something that almost do what I want !

```
class DiceWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onRolled;

  DiceWidget(this.onRolled);

  @override
  _DiceWidgetState createState() => _DiceWidgetState();
}

class _DiceWidgetState extends State<DiceWidget> {
  static Dice dice = Dice();
  MaterialColor diceColor = dice.getColor;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            dice.rollDice();
            setState(() {
              diceColor = dice.getColor;
            });
            sleep(Duration(milliseconds: i * 100));
          }
          widget.onRolled(diceColor);
        },
        color: diceColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can instatiate a DiceWidget and give it a function to execute after the rolling, to process the result (the color randomly chosen).

I now have a problem with the "animation" I'm trying to make, I don't like my solution (and it doesn't work anyway...)
Is there a "nicer" way to achieve this "rolling effect" ?

Thanks for your answers, 
Axel.